# sftp configuration in redhat

Tags: linux, sftp, redhat

I am creating sftp configuration in redhat machine, but on the time of restarting ssh service getting below error.

```
$ service sshd restart
Stopping sshd:                                             [  OK  ]
Starting sshd: /etc/ssh/sshd_config: line 130: Bad configuration option: Match
/etc/ssh/sshd_config: line 132: Bad configuration option: ForceCommand
/etc/ssh/sshd_config: terminating, 2 bad configuration options
                                                           [FAILED]
```

My O.S.

```
$ cat /etc/redhat-release 
Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 5.4 (Tikanga)
```

Comment: Can you post your `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` file?

Comment: ##Subsystem     sftp    /usr/libexec/openssh/sftp-server

Subsystem       sftp    internal-sftp
Match Group sftpusers
ChrootDirectory /sftp/%u
ForceCommand internal-sftp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Red Hat Enterprise Linux 5 is very old (released 10 years ago) and does not support these configuration options (`Match`, `ForceCommand`). You should consider updating to something more recent if you want to have access to the newest features.

Comment: Please elaborate, what I need to update, I have the root access.

Comment: Also please let me know is any other way to achieve sftp in this O.S.

Comment: The whole OS. There are no software/package updates for RHEL5 that would bring this functionality in.